# Matlab: polar coordinates grey scale plot

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, polar-coordinates

**edit: I decided to split this question into two parts, because it were really two questions: 1. how to make a polar surface plot in MATLAB (this question) and [2. how to put fit polar data points into a coarse (and non-polar) matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37182879/plot-polar-grey-values-in-matrix-without-interpolating-every-for-loop)**

I have a matrix that contains certain grey values (values between zero and one). These points are stored in a rectangular matrix, but really the data points are acquired by rotating the detector. This means that I actually have polar coordinates (I know the polar coordinates for every single pixel in my starting matrix).

I want to make a polar plot of the data points. I have the example of this below.

[image: Image as I want it]

Because MATLAB stores images as matrices, the polar coordinates I have do not exactly match the 'bins' of the matrix. Therefore, we currently use an interpolation algorithm to put the polar coordinates into a square matrix. However, this is extremely slow. I see two methods to solve this issue:

1. let MATLAB directly plot the data points as polar.
2. <strike>[calculate once how to convert from the start matrix to the end matrix and let MATLAB do this through matrix multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37182879/plot-polar-grey-values-in-matrix-without-interpolating-every-for-loop).</strike>

Some basic information:

Input matrix size: 512×960

Current output matrix size: 1024×1024

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change an image from (x y )coordinate to polar coordinate matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580623/how-to-change-an-image-from-x-y-coordinate-to-polar-coordinate-matlab)

Comment: @tvo, I'm afraid it is not a duplicate. They have a cartesian image and want to make a polar image out of it. I have polar coordinates and values, but I want to plot is as polar as well, which is something I don't seem to be able to.

Comment: I messed up when flagging the duplicate. I meant to flag this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12924598/examples-to-convert-image-to-polar-coordinates-do-it-explicitly-want-a-slick-m. Could be it's not a duplicate, but it may be helpful to have a look.

Comment: Thanks for the link, unfortunately the solution there uses the same slow interpolation step we use now. Since my goal is creating a faster code (we already have a slow one), I'm afraid this does not help me.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is built in function for polar plot in matlab.

```
Z = [2+3i 2 -1+4i 3-4i 5+2i -4-2i -2+3i -2 -3i 3i-2i];
polarplot(Z,'*')
```

this command plots:
[plot polar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzKuD.png)

See this link:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polarplot.html

To plot in grayscale, use "pcolor" and specify colormap to "gray"

www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ pcolor.html

Comment: This just plots polar points, not grey values right? If I'm mistaken, please elaborate on how I could use this in my case.

Comment: if you need to plot in grayscale you can use "pcolor"

Comment: Do you understand how pcolor works? I have a matrix with all the X and Y positions for my plot. I also have the matrix with the grey values, which I can relate to that. What should C be `code`(pcolor(X,Y,C))`code` to then get the correct plot.

Comment: yes I do understand. you know the range for r and theta.. say r=0:.1:3, theta= -pi:0.001:pi, then C will have size length(r)* length(theta) .. then use this code....  X = r*cos(theta);
Y = r*sin(theta);
C = r*cos(2*theta);
pcolor(X,Y,C)

Comment: I do not think that this is very clear, but I figured out in the end that what I should specify is that C equals the matrix of grey values I have. Then I get a plot which looks completely black, because the grid-lines are black and there are 960 of them radially. Therefore, I could not use pcolor, but you did put me on the right track.

Comment: Thanks for your help though, you pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: great !! I am happy to know that your problem is solved though i couldn't help much.

Answer (score 2):

The question was solved (apart from a minor flaw), partially because K.M. Shihab Uddin pointed me in the right direction. Unfortunately, using surf means continuously really plotting the image in a figure, and this is slow as well.

So I have X and Y values both in separate matrices and greyscale values (in a matrix called C) for every X and Y combination.

I found out that pcolor is just surf with a viewpoint from the top. So I used the following code to plot my graph.

```
surf(X,Y,C*255)
view([0,0,500])
```

However, this gave me a completely black image. This is because surf (and pcolor) create 960 grid lines radially in my case. The solution is to use:

```
surf(X,Y,img2*255,'EdgeColor','none')
view([0,0,500])
```

Now I have an almost perfect image, like I had before. Only, of my 960 radial lines, one is left white, so I still have to solve that. However, I feel this is a technical detail of the function surf, and answering this part does not belong in this question.

[The resulting image](http://static.tweakers.net/ext/f/vPV1WX5nTflMYpa3nbfeLgIc/full.png)