# plot polar grey values in matrix without interpolating every for loop

Tags: matlab, matrix, polar-coordinates

I have a matrix with grey values between `0` and `1`. For every entry in the matrix, there are certain polar coordinates that indicate the position of the grey values. I already have either `Theta` and `Rho` values (polar) ,both in separate 512×960 matrices. And grayscale values (in a matrix called `C`) for every `Theta` and `Rho` combination. I have the same for `X` and `Y`, as I just use `pol2cart` for the transformation. The problem is that I cannot directly plot these values, as they do not yet fit in the 'bins' of the new matrix.

What I want: to put the grey values in a square matrix of size 1024×1024. I cannot do this directly, because the polar coordinates fall in between the grid of this matrix. Therefore, we now use interpolation, but this is extremely time consuming and has to be done separately for every dataset, although the transformation from the original matrices to this final one will always be the same. Therefore, I'd like to solve this matrix once (either analytically or numerically) and use a matrix multiplication or something similar to apply the manipulation efficiently in every cycle of the code.

One example of what one of these transformations could look like this:

[image]

The zeros in the first matrix are the grid, and the value `1` (in between the grid) is the grey value that falls in between four grid points, then I'd like to transform to the second matrix (don't mind the visual spacing between the points).

For every dataset, I have hundreds of these matrices, so I would like to make the code more efficient.

Background: I'm using `TriScatteredInterp` now for the interpolation. We tried `scatteredInterpolant` as well, but that is slower. I also posted [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37170450/matlab-polar-coordinates-grey-scale-plot), but decided to split the two possible solutions, because the solution I ask for here is also applicable to non-MATLAB code and will probably be faster and makes for a smoother (no continuous popping up of figures) execution of the code.

Comment: Please do not hesitate to ask me to make the question clearer. I struggled a bit with making the problem clear, but I am very willing to improve the question and make examples (where it would be preferable that the example is well described).

Comment: Not an answer, but maybe it helps you a bit: If you look into the source of the `interp2` function (assuming you use this?), are there some steps you can skip, and then make your own implementation which exploits this? I am not sure if it is possible, however.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That seems like a good idea, I will definitely look into that. Of course, your comment still holds for whatever other interpolation function I use.

Comment: Well, sooner or later you will run into a built-in function, which does only lists some instructions, but no actual source.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how it works in `interp2`, because the source code for that seems to be open. If I try to open the code behind scatteredInterpolant, I just get a help file. However, interp2 does not work for my inputs yet, so I am trying to fix the code such that it does. I'll report back when that is finished (unfortunately I cannot spend too much time on this, since it is a side-track of my work). In the mean time, should anyone have other suggestions, I'm looking forward to them.

Comment: OK, so, what are `X` and `Y`, because you say they are *polar* coordinates? Which is the angle, and which the radius? Or are the `X` and `Y` already converted to Cartesian coordinates?

Comment: Are the `X` and `Y sorted or replicated in any way? ...you can perhaps best post some simple 5×5 input data we can play with.

Comment: #Rody Thank you for your comment. I will try to post some simple examples tomorrow. In the meantime, I changed the question to make it more clear. I have polar coordinates, or carthesian. Whichever is more useful to you.

Comment: OK. Are the the coordinates regularly spaced, or scattered?

Comment: Also, is there some reason to believe that inter-coordinate color values are related to more coordinates than just the nearest neighbors? As in, is the color progression expected to follow some sort of function of θ and ρ?

Comment: The values are regularly spaced in theta and regularly spaced in rho. Also see the related question for some more information on what I want to use it for. http://stackoverflow.com/q/37170450/5569238  . Nearest neighbour is good enough. The values are pixels. They will not be 100% independent close to rho=0 but they should be at higher rho values. They are independent enough that it is not necessary to take it into account.

Comment: Do you maybe have the image processing toolbox? Because `imresize` looks more like what you want

Comment: I do have the image processing toolbox. The problem is that I have these values, but they do not fit in a normal matrix, and therefore do not constitute an image. Or is there a way to use `imresize` with values that do not constitute an image? (I have x-values, y-values and intensity values separately, they are regularly spaced in theta and regularly spaced in rho)

Answer (score 3):

### Using the image processing toolbox

Images work a bit differently than the data you have. However, it's fairly straightforward to map one representation into the other.

There is only one problem I see: wrapping. Obviously, θ = 2π = 0, but MATLAB does not know that. AFAIK, there is no easy way to tell MATLAB that.

Why does this matter? Well, simply put, inter-pixel interpolation uses information from the nearest `N` neighbors to find intermediate colors, with `N` depending on the interpolation kernel. When doing this somewhere in the middle of the image there is no problem, but at the edges MATLAB has to know that the left edge equals the right edge. This is not standard image processing, and I'm not aware of any function that is capable of this.

### Implementation

Now, when disregarding the wrapping problem, this is one way to do it:

```
function resize_polar()

    %% ORIGINAL IMAGE
    % ==========================================================================

    % Some random greyscale data
    C = double(rgb2gray(imread('stars.png')))/255;

    % Your current size, and desired size    
    sz_x = size(C,2);    new_sz_x = 1024;
    sz_y = size(C,1);    new_sz_y = 1024;

    % Ranges for teat and rho;  
    % replace with your actual values
    rho_start = 0;     theta_start = 0;
    rho_end   = 10;    theta_end   = 2*pi;

    % Generate regularly spaced grid;
    theta = linspace(theta_start, theta_end, sz_x);
    rho   = linspace(rho_start,   rho_end,   sz_y);

    [theta, rho] = meshgrid(theta,rho);


    % Make plot of generated data
    plot_polar(theta, rho, C, 'Original image');

    % Resize data
    [theta,rho,C] = resize_polar_data(theta, rho, C, [new_sz_y new_sz_x]);

    % Make plot of generated data
    plot_polar(theta, rho, C, 'Rescaled image');

end


function [theta,rho,data] = resize_polar_data(theta,rho,data, new_dims)

    % Create fake RGB image cube 
    IMG = cat(3, theta,rho,data);

    % Rescale as if theta and rho are RG color data in the RGB
    % image cube
    IMG = imresize(IMG, new_dims, 'nearest');

    % Split up the data again
    theta = IMG(:,:,1);
    rho   = IMG(:,:,2);
    data  = IMG(:,:,3);

end

function plot_polar(theta, rho, data, label)

    [X,Y] = pol2cart(theta, rho);

    figure('renderer', 'opengl')
    clf, hold on

    surf(X,Y,zeros(size(X)), data, ...
         'edgecolor', 'none');     
    colormap gray

    title(label);

end
```

The images used and plotted:

**Le awesomely-drawn 512×960 PNG image**
[image: stars made with MS Paint]

[image: The original]

[image: The rescaled image]

Now, the two look the same (couldn't really come up with a better-suited image), so you'll have to believe me that the 512×960 has indeed been rescaled to 1024×1024, with nearest-neighbor interpolation.

Here are some timings for the actual `imresize()` operation for some simple kernels:

```
nearest : 0.008511 seconds.
bilinear: 0.019651 seconds.
bicubic : 0.025390 seconds.  <-- default kernel
```

But this depends strongly on your hardware; I believe `imresize` offloads a lot of work to the GPU, so if you have a crappy one, it'll be slower.

### Wrapping

If the wrapping problem is really important to you, you can modify the function above to do the following:

- first, rescale the image with `imresize()` like before
- horizontally concatenate the **second** half of the grayscale data and the **first** half. Meaning, you swap the first and second halves to make the left and right edges (0 and 2π) touch in the middle.
- rescale this intermediate image with `imresize()`
- Extract the central vertical strip of the rescaled intermediate image
- split that up in two equal-width strips
- and replace the edge strips of the output image with the two strips you just created

Now, this is kind of a brute force approach: you are re-scaling an image *twice*, and most of the pixels of the second image round will be discarded. If performance is a problem, you can of course apply the rescale to only the  central strip of that intermediate image. But, well, that will be a bit more complicated.